# How to create api with magento step by step

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, soap, soap-api-v2

I want to create **SOAP API** for mobile app

1. Product
2. Product List
3. Category List
4. Customer

I'm new to **API** and found many results none of extension works for me.

I have created Webservices user and role but don't how to use it.

Also suggest me `url`how to fetch data.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is solve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php

    $client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');

    // If somestuff requires api authentification,
    // then get a session token
    $session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');

    $result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.list'); // Product list

    $result = $client->call($session, 'customer.list'); // Customer list
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($result);

    ?>
```

For More information follow the link:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalog.html

Comment: Where i have to put this code on root i dont know.

Comment: create a PHP file(ex.: soap.php) on root then hit the URL:

For example:   http://www.example.com/soap.php

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below code-

```
<?php

        $SoapClient = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl'); 

        $auth = $SoapClient->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');

        $productlist  = $SoapClient->call($auth, 'catalog_product.list'); // Product list

        $customerlist = $SoapClient->call($auth, 'customer.list'); // Customer list

        $categorylist = $SoapClient->call($auth, 'catalog_category.level'); // Product list
    ?>
```